# jQuery MultiSelect by Eric Hynds -- How to get the checked options

Tags: jquery, multi-select

Could someone please help me to get the selected options from the jQuery MultiSelect by Eric Hynds and insert them into a sdf file using razor syntax

Here is my Razor + HTML code-- I'm usin webmatrix startersite as the template

```
@{  var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Details where team like 'EMT'";
    }
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ms.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $("select").multiselect();
    });
    $(function ()
    {
        $("input[type=submit]").button();
    });


</script>
<link href="~/Content/ms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<form method="post">




    <select multiple id="all" name="all" multiple="Multiple">
                @{foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
          {
            <option>@row.fname</option>
          }

         }
    </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Send Report" id="Repot" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add items to an array for selected options on click and then use that array for later use. See [documentation](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) for various events.

> ***click*** :     Fires when a checkbox is checked or unchecked. js
>   $("#multiselect").on("multiselectclick", function(event, ui) { /*
>   event: the original event object ui.value: value of the checkbox
>   ui.text: text of the checkbox ui.checked: whether or not the input was
>   checked or unchecked (boolean) */ });

Something like this

```
$("select").multiselect({
    click: function(event, ui){
        if(ui.checked){//if checked
          ...push the value into array
        }
        else {//if unchecked
          ...remove that value from array
        }
    }
});
```

**Update**

At their [site](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) it's mentioned. (Search for 'How do I...?')

> Retrieve all selected values?
>
> The easiest way is to call val() on the select box:

```
var values = $("select").val();
```

> The same can be accomplished using the multiselect API. Call the
>   getChecked method and map a new array:

```
var array_of_checked_values = $("select").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
   return this.value;    
}).get();
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am right but I am using the jquery plugin by Eric Hynds and need some help with the getchecked() method associated with it.
getChecked Returns an array of all the checked checkboxes.

http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Comment: The code above is using Eric Hynds plugin. I was adding selected options in an array when you select it. What is the exact issue you facing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I need to get the checked items from the multiselect and insert them into a database in cshtml.

Comment: See update to answer. Hope that helps. You will get the checked items.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit too late for your project, but it will hopefully help someone else.

I use the simpler approach in the update:

```
    var values = $("select").val();
```

So if you have checked options 2, 4 and 6, the "values" will be a string like this: "2,4,6". If you are developing an MVC project, you need to save this string in a hidden field on the form, otherwise the controller won't have access to it. In my code, I am using the "close" event to write the output (i.e. 2,4,6) to a hidden textbox called "output".

some code snippets:

Create a hidden field on the form:

```
    @Html.Hidden("output", null)
```

Define the "close" event handler in the initial multiselect definition:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $('select').multiselect(function() {
           //your code
           close: function(event, ui){
               var values = $('select').val();
               $('#output').val(values);
               // you can inspect the value using alert(values); 
           },
           // your code
           // your code
        });
    </script>
```

Now in the post back part of your edit action, form["output"] is equal to "2,4,6".

How to use this to update your database depends on a lot of parameters in you project. If you have been sticking to the MVC pattern guidelines, you just need refresh your model in the controller Edit action and the call the update (or put) method with the modified model.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Nasser.